# Issues about Ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have used three select boxes with the same class along with a radio button. How can I get the selected values of dropdown in ajax response?

My problem is, I am getting the first select box in ajax, but when I try to select the second or third, I am getting an empty value.

Can you tell me where is the mistake or give me ideas for taking values in ajax?

Here is the code:

```
<td><input type="radio" id="active_btn" name="status" value="yes">Active</td>
        <td><select class="desig_opt" name="select_opt" ><option value="" >Select</option><option value="Admin" >Admin</option>
    <option value="Staff" >Staff</option></select></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="deactive_btn" name="status" value="no">Deactive</td>
        <td><select class="desig_opt" name="select_opt" ><option value="" >Select</option><option value="Admin" >Admin</option>
    <option value="Staff" >Staff</option></select></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="both_btn" name="status" value="both">Both</td>
         <td><select class="desig_opt" name="select_opt"> <option value="" >Select</option><option value="Admin" >Admin</option>
    <option value="Staff">Staff</option></select></td>
```

In ajax reponse I used the line below to get the selected value:

```
var admin=$(".desig_opt option:selected").val();
```

Is it the right way of taking the values? If not, can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(".desig_opt option:selected") , returns an array.
```

Try

JS

```
function test(){

   var admin=$(".desig_opt option:selected");


    $.each(admin, function( index, value ) {
        alert( $(admin[index]).val() );
    });       

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6sh8a6qa/)

Maybe you could store the values in other array like

```
function test(){

   var admin=$(".desig_opt option:selected");

    var data = [];

    $.each(admin, function( index, value ) {
        // validate if $(admin[index]).val() != '' before add ?? 
        data.push($(admin[index]).val());
    });

    alert(data);

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6sh8a6qa/3/)

Comment: Thank You very much for the fast reply i got the answer. Its working

Comment: I have one more doubt regarding the above question. I have used three radio button and select box. With same name of radio button we can able to select one radio button at a time. AS it is, is it possible to select one drop down values at a time. i.e: If i select second select box values the selected values in the first one should become to empty. Pls anyone of u help me to get the solution.                                                                                 Thanks in advance

Comment: @Vidyut Then, you only need only one drop down list.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign separate id to each of your select dropdowns so that you can get them individually to send in your ajax data.

For example;

```
var admin1= $('#desig_opt1').find('option:selected').attr("value");
var admin2= $('#desig_opt2').find('option:selected').attr("value");
var admin3= $('#desig_opt3').find('option:selected').attr("value");
```

Check out the response in [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sw548ev4/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am getting values with different id too.